# load more content when user scrolls to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page on a website that is a giant list of logos. i only want to load the first 12 logos, and load 12 more when the user gets to the bottom of the page. i've seen this done all over the place, but i'm trying to figure out how to do it.

i don't want to load all the logos at once and then hide most of them, because the user is still going to have to wait for them to load...

currently all my images are in the same document, and they are each in their own div (such as #loadContent1, #loadContent2, etc). what is the best way to accomplish this feature?

thanks

Comment: [This is what you want.](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/infinite-scroll/

Comment: the infinite-scroll plugin works with wordpress posts. how do i make it work for images on a page? where do i put the hidden content before i load it into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery Plugin that called **Lazy Load** that can maybe assist you.

[Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)